# StickyTableHeaders Cloned width issue

Tags: jquery, css

I have a fully Dynamic table, i successfully included the stickey table header plugin in my table.But the problem is header data width is not equel to the cloned header data width. how can i fix this problem

```
#mytable table td, #mytable table th {
padding: 1em 1.5em;
text-align: left;
}
```

Comment: Would you include minimal code to reproduce your problem and specify expected and actual behaviour clearer?

Answer (score 1):

**Solution**

After you clone the table head, you should also copy over and apply current table head cell widths (from original table): calculated by browser, not what you have inside CSS.

**Explanation**

It does not matter if you set you table head cells width to 50px, they can be wider or smaller. For example: if some of the cells inside table body is wider (long word), than table head cell gets wider too. Now, looking at your cloned table head: same table header cell is still 50px, because there is no body cell to push it wider.